# Why the AKA prefix?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, title, jessica-jones

The episode titles for the Jessica Jones episodes are all prefixed with AKA, which stands for Also Known As.  I'm curious/confused why this decision was made.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

***Jessica Jones*** is a series revolving around Private Detective Jessica Jones and her agency *"Alias Investigations"*. The series is based on the comic ***Alias***, and the Netflix series was originally titled ***A.K.A. Jessica Jones***. As in *'Alias [Investigations], Also Known As Jessica Jones.'*

When they pared down the name, the A.K.A. was kept as a nod to that. [From wiki for Jessica Jones (TV Series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Jones_(TV_series)#Development):

> In December 2014, the official title was revealed to be Marvel's A.K.A. Jessica Jones. However, in June 2015, Marvel revealed that the title for the series would be shortened to Marvel's Jessica Jones. On why the title was shortened, [Head of Marvel TV Jeph Loeb] said, **"It literally just became one of those things that happens. We had talked about whether that was the best title for it, and that’s how it happened."** Rosenberg added that the "AKA" is "living in the episodes. You'll still see it."

[From the source interview,](http://collider.com/jessica-jones-tone-action-melissa-rosenberg-jeph-loeb-interview/) they expand on why AKA was used in the first place:

> **LOEB:** **As many people know, at one point, this show was called to as AKA Jessica Jones, so we used to refer to the AKA of it.** Every single person has an AKA in their life. This is the person that they present, and then this is the person that they actually are. How true is that in life?

With the underlying theme of the comic and the show being that *all is not what it seems*, the episode titles have sought to reflect that.

In general, it's also a nod to the entire private detective genre.